# Sitecore Media File AutoPublish

Tags: caching, sitecore, publish, media-library

I have set Media file autoPublish as soon as file is uploaded into media library by using workflow (the initial state is autoPublish).

I know that whenever item is published, all HTML cache will be cleared. This means whenever media file is uploaded (published), all HTML cache are gone.

If this is correct, do you think that autoPublish for media item makes a bad impact in Sitecore performance and webpage rendering??

Because there would be many editors to create/update page items with new media files and reducing the step of work process would be a good idea for them.

However, on developer and system admin sides, it would not be a good way in the Sitecore performance.

What do you think??? Setting scheduled publish would be better?? twice a week??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that in cases where cache clearing might result in performance issues, particularly in large instances with frequent small publishes, Sitecore themselves recommend scheduled publishing.

However I think something more like every 30 minutes is more practical than twice a week.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. So, that means the frequent publish impacts on Sitecore performance even the publish is only one tiny media file... :(